# mongodb in bash/shell: try to fetch specific values from CLI

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, mongo-shell

I try to use 'mongoexport' to retrieve the 'Url' value:

```
$ mongoexport -d "db" -c "collection" -q '{"Id":"5400490185"} | jq .
```

return:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641e8845c0a3fde195b5901b"
  },
  "Url": "https://example.org",
  "Id": "5400490185",
  "Title": "xxx",
  "Description": "foobar",
  "Date_Time": "1679697365"
}
```

Now I try to fetch only 'Url', from the doc https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-comparison/ should be

```
db.people.find(
    { status: "A" },
    { user_id: 1, status: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

so I try:

```
$ mongoexport -d "db" -c "collection" -q '{"Id":"5400490185"}, {"Url": "1", _id: "0"}'
```

but I get

```
invalid character ',' after top-level value
```

What's wrong?

Tried also:

```
$ mongoexport -d "db" -c "collection" -q '{"Id":"5400490185"}' -f 'Url'
```

But doesn't produce what's expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far easier in Python and shell here-doc ('mongodb' JS query syntax is awful IMHO):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mydb='foobar'

if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
    cat<<-EOF >&2
    Usage: ${0##*/} <collection> [id]
    EOF
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $2 ]]; then
    python<<-EOF
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    mydb = client['$mydb']
    mycol = mydb["${1:?}"]
    c = mycol.find_one({"Id": "$2"})
    print(c['Title'], c['Description'], c['Url'], sep="\\n")
    client.close()
    EOF
else
    python<<-EOF
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    mydb = client['texas']
    mycol = mydb["${1:?}"]
    for c in mycol.find():
        print(c['Url'], c['Title'], c['Description'], sep="\\n")
    client.close()
    EOF
fi
```

Usage:

```
Usage mongo-parse.sh <collection> [id]
```

Simple, clear, efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

```
$ mongoexport -d "db" -c "collection" -q '{"Id":"5400490185"}'  --jsonArray | jq '.[] | .Url'
```

But I guess there's a better way to do it without a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `mongosh`:

```
db.people.find(
    { status: "A" }
).forEach({doc => 
   print(doc.Url)
})
```

If it does not work, try `db.people.find(...).toArray().forEach(...)`.

As a one-liner

```
mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017/db" --quiet --eval "db.collection.find({ 'Id': '5400490185'}).forEach(doc => {print(doc.Url)})"
https://example.org
```

Comment: Is it a typo, `coc` vs `doc`?

Comment: Anyway, none works

Comment: Yes, was a typo. What do you mean by "none works"? Note, without URL, the default database `test` is used. Try `db.getSiblingDB("db").people....` or specify the database in [connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: This gives me an error, see https://hastebin.com/share/zanefenoqa.swift

Comment: Please see my update, for me it is working. Maybe enclose the connection string also by quotes.

Comment: Gives me a syntax error on `=>` symbol (that you can read in my link) https://hastebin.com/share/mohenozaxi.javascript

Comment: That's really strange. Can you run a simple `find` (without forEach) in the shell? Maybe it is a new bug in version 1.8. I am using mongosh version 1.6